# Logstash - Grok filter - Is it possible to name aggregated patterns

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

I've got this time stamp in one of the logs

```
Tue Mar 29 09:47:33 2016
```

I've looked into the built in patterns https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns

But couldn't find an exact match.

I know I can create my custom pattern.. But I would still like to resolve it cleaner at the filter level.

I was thinking of a grok pattern in this format:

```
%{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{YEAR}
```

But not sure how to name it matched it to a single name

Answer (score 0):

Got it...

```
(?<sourceTimestamp>%{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{YEAR})
```